Windows configured sandbox file that has full access to local folder but can't make changes to the local folder
I'm running a wsb file with just the basic configuration:
`    <Configuration>
  <MappedFolders>
    <MappedFolder>
    <ProtectedClient>enable</ProtectedClient>
      <HostFolder>C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Games\</HostFolder>
      <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>
    </MappedFolder>
  </MappedFolders>
</Configuration>    `

I'm first trying this on a basic game folder before any risky program that I've decided to download. In case I find a program that is useful, but I don't trust to run normally, I would like for it to work and have all the changes and logged and saved in the sanbox folder, then later be able to copy them to my local folder if they're just files or information.
Using <HostFolder> works well with keeping said game folder instead of having to copy and paste data every time, but any changes I make in the <HostFolder> from sandbox affects my local folder which doesn't seem safe to me. How can I make the changes from sandbox only one way? So that they only happen in sandbox. Also, <ReadOnly>true</> Doesn't help with opening save files, and access to other files in the same directory from the program running. I feel that <ReadOnly>false</> would be giving the program too much power, althought if the threats and changes are only in sandbox then it doesn't really matter. Any suggestions?
